# Difference in Cell Locking between Macro File and Standard when using IFERROR(VLOOKUP)

Tags: excel, vba

Entering an Account number in Col C, a `vlookup` table obtains a members name for Col D using

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C4,MembersAndIDList,2,FALSE),"").
```

The code works fine except if the used types into Col C, and presses delete key, as this removes the formula. The formula is used in all cells in Col D
Using Excel 2010 - I can lock a `Vlookup` Column to prevent inadvertent over typing on an xlsx file, but the lock doesn’t work on an xlsm file. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013 and Excel 2010, and in both versions I can lock cells in a spreadsheet within an xlsm file.  (And what has this question got to do with [excel-vba]?)

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in the code module of the sheet on which the user should enter the membership number.

> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
>
> ```
> Dim Rng As Range
> Dim Member As String
>
> Set Rng = Range("MembersAndIDList")
> With Target
>     If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub                       ' exclude first row at the top
>
>     If .Column = 3 Then                             ' Column 3 = "C"
>         Application.EnableEvents = False
>         On Error Resume Next
>         Member = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Value, Rng, 2, False)
>         If Err Then
>             MsgBox "Please enter a valid member number", _
>                    vbExclamation, "Invalid entry"
>             .Value = ""
>             .Select
>         Else
>             Cells(.Row, 4).Value = Member           ' column 4 = "D"
>         End If
>         Application.EnableEvents = True
>     End If
> End With
> ```
>
> End Sub

You can modify the Row < 2 to exclude more header rows, change the name of your list or the message text and, of course, the columns C and D, but you will need to continue using your worksheet function on workbooks which aren't macro enabled and therefore can't have this code.

Comment: Thanks for the information, will give that a go. Did find that allowing users to Select Locked Cells and Select Unlocked Cells in the xlsx situation prevents overwriting of the formula, but the same condition in the Macro file allows overwriting. Deselecting Allow Select Locked Cells does prevent the problem I was having